# Commas disappearing when user inputs a decimal point in a input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a code through jQuery that automatically inputs commas into large numbers when a user types them into a textbox. For ex: 1,000, 1,000,000, 10,000. I got this running, however when a user tries to type in a number that has a decimal point for ex. 1,000.50 the commas dissappear.

Here is the code to automatically input the commas:

```
$("input[data-type='number']").keyup(function(event){


  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "");
  var num2 = num.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
  console.log(num2);
  // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
  $this.val(num2);
});
```

How can I keep the program from deleting the comma values when a user inputs a decimal point?

Comment: Well looks like your reg exp for not allow for decimal points.

Comment: JS has [tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to redo the reg exp to allow decimals, you can split on the decimal and join back after the replacement

```
var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("."),
    num2 = "";
if (num.length) {
    num[0] = num[0].split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
    num2 = num.join(".");
}
```